# Scraping Dawn news website returns (referer:None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

The results of my scrapping code returns (referer: none) for a news website following is the code,I have tried this same code for BBC and it works fine but for this website it is not returning the desired results.The

```
import os
import scrapy


newpath = 'urdu_data' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)


class UrduSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "urdu"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/latest-news'
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/news'
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/tech'
    ]

    def should_process_page(self, page_url):



        for s_url in self.start_urls:
            if page_url.startswith(s_url) and page_url != s_url:
                return True

        return False

    def parse(self, response):

        if self.should_process_page(response.url):
            page_id = response.url.split("/")[-1]
            filename = page_id + '.txt'

            # if response has story body, we save it's contents
            story_body = response.css('div.story__content')
            story_paragraphs_text = story_body.css('p::text')
            page_data = ''
            for p in story_paragraphs_text:
                page_data += p.extract() + '\n'

            if page_data:
                open('urdu_data/' + filename, 'w').write(page_data)

            # Now follow any links that are present on the page
            links = response.css('a.title-link ::attr(href)').extract()
            for link in links:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    response.urljoin(link),
                    callback=self.parse
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have the start_urls like below

```
start_urls = [
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/latest-news',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/news',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/tech'
    ]
```

You dont have the urls separated by commas in the code mentioned above so it is take only two urls the first one and the other three are appended and used as one url please put commas after each url as mentioned above

Next `story_body = response.css('div.story__content')` means in the page given by the url there should be a div element with class=story__content which i think is missing in the mentioned urls.Just having a quick look at the html of https://www.dawnnews.tv it seems it has something like story__excerpt as div class not sure if this is what you require.Anyway you need to check the html of these pages and get the correct contents.

### What you can do to debug this is to use print statements and print out story_body,story_paragraphs_text and check whether you are getting any output for these.Hope this will be helpful for you to do the required debugging.

```
017-10-23 22:11:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.dawnnews.tv> (referer: None)
https://www.dawnnews.tv
2017-10-23 22:11:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.dawnnews.tv/news> (referer: None)
https://www.dawnnews.tv/news
news.txt
[]
2017-10-23 22:11:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.dawnnews.tv/tech> (referer: None)
https://www.dawnnews.tv/tech
tech.txt
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">فیس '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">یوٹی'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">واٹس'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">ویب '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">ابھی'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">8 سا'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">اسما'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">دنیا'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">فیس '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">سوشل'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        "> فیس'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">اگر '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">اس ف'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">بہت '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">اب پ'>]
2017-10-23 22:11:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.dawnnews.tv/latest-news> (referer: None)
https://www.dawnnews.tv/latest-news
latest-news.txt
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">فلم '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">فیس '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">چیئر'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">غذا '>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">جوڈی'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">ہولی'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]" data='<div class="story__excerpt        ">پاکس'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' story__excerpt ')]"       ">
```

---

code used for above

```
import os
import scrapy


newpath = 'urdu_data' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)


class UrduSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "urdu"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/latest-news',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/news',
        'https://www.dawnnews.tv/tech'
    ]

    def should_process_page(self, page_url):



        for s_url in self.start_urls:
            if page_url.startswith(s_url) and page_url != s_url:
                return True

        return False

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        if self.should_process_page(response.url):
            page_id = response.url.split("/")[-1]
            filename = page_id + '.txt'
            print(filename)

            # if response has story body, we save it's contents
            story_body = response.css('div.story__excerpt')
            print(story_body)
            story_paragraphs_text = story_body.css('p::text')
            page_data = ''
            for p in story_paragraphs_text:
                page_data += p.extract() + '\n'

            if page_data:
                open('urdu_data/' + filename, 'w').write(page_data)

            # Now follow any links that are present on the page
            links = response.css('a.title-link ::attr(href)').extract()
            for link in links:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    response.urljoin(link),
                    callback=self.parse
                )
```

---

You need to make similar changes to get the response from other elements based on the html structure of the page.

Comment: we have tried all this and checked and used the correct class names.

Comment: It should work properly if use the correct elements to get your required response.Referer None is not an error it just means that url is not referred from another url.I have added some logs i get when using scrapy with the changes i mentioned in code in the answer.If you use the correct elements for the others you should get the correct response

Comment: thank you so much i tried your code.but when i click on a news from main page. i found tag of "story__content pt-0 pt-sm-4" but when i print paragraphs it don't show anything. i dont know.but i will check it again .